# Blackhole Entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy

What happens if substance with zero entropy falls into a Scharzschild blackhole? Since $$S=\frac{k_b A}{4L^2_p},$$ increase in mass should be accompanied by an increase in entropy. Its area can not increase, since that would imply spontaneous creation of microstates, but its mass should increase. How to resolve the apparent paradox?

Comment: Can you give an example for "a substance with zero entropy"? Note that absolute zero cannot be achieved with finitely many thermodynamic processes.

Comment: Theoretically speaking, supposing you have created a perfectly crystalline substance at absolute zero temperature. Also, since blackholes appear to violate the Nernst-Simon statement of the third law of thermodynamics (ref: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bekenstein-Hawking_entropy), we may be able to achieve the required configuration if another blackhole can be taken to zero temperature, thus having zero entropy, and made to merge with the former one.

Comment: Why would you think that “spontaneous creation of microstates” is forbidden? In a non-gravitational example consider two different gases that are allowed to mix by, say, opening a valve. The moment the valve is open we have new microstates where both types of molecules can occupy all parts of the system.

Answer (score 0):

The area of a black-hole's (Schwarzschild) envelope **DOES increase** in proportion to the energy added from an exterior source.  The value of the energy density (2E/r) is constant for all black-holes...so if energy (E) is increased, 'r', the Schwarzschild radius, must also increase, as well as BH entropy (expressed on the Schwarzschild "surface".